# secured ashx file failed while calling ajax from firefox

Tags: asp.net, ajax, firefox, asp.net-membership, handler

I build an upload handler (ashx file)

but i want that just registerd user can use this handler

i add the web config ()

this work good when i try open the handler direct

but when i get the handler using ajax
its work good in chrome and explorer 
but fail on Firefox

here is all the relevant files
http://img2.timg.co.il/forums/1_173216074.JPG

any idea what can i do to fix this?
thanks

Comment: Please show your code?

Comment: you can see all the code in the attached image here http://img2.timg.co.il/forums/1_173216074.JPG

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i found the solution here http://geekswithblogs.net/apopovsky/archive/2009/05/06/working-around-flash-cookie-bug-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx

the problem is flash cookies

thanks!